# Dividir cadena en n palabras Javasript

Tags: javascript

Requiero dividir una cadena en partes, cada una de 10 de palabras.
Por ejemplo, la cadena:

```javascript
let cadena = "atención la descripción de los síntomas, revisó detenidamente las zonas afectadas y explicó detalladamente el problema y el uso de los medicamentos que recetó".
```

Tras dividirse quedaría como:

```javascript
[
    [atención la descripción de los síntomas, revisó detenidamente las zonas]
    [afectadas y explicó detalladamente el problema y el uso de los]
    [medicamentos que recetó]
]
```

Para ello he utilizado la función `split`. Esto me devuelve un arreglo de palabras, pero aún no consigo cómo unirlas por grupos de 10 palabras

```javascript
palabras=cadena.split('')
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el resultado que esperas obtener? Dices 2 partes, cuales erian esas partes

Comment: desearia el resultado de acuerdo a 10 palabras

Comment: Me parece que buscas [algo como esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6259543/5587982). Sólo cambia el `3` por `10` y lo tendrás.

Comment: eso es para n caracteres y yo necesito para n palabras

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La solución más sencilla que pude idear es simplemente separar la frase en tokens (espacios en este caso) con el método [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) de ahí solamente es unirlos en grupos de 10.

Para ello se usa [`splice(0, 10)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), el cual modifica el arreglo original y devuelve un subarreglo, el que posteriormente vamos a unir con el método [`join(" ")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), el cual va a unir todos los elementos de ese arreglo con el token especificado o por defecto una coma.

Como nota, fíjate que lo anterior se repetirá hasta que el arreglo dividido por espacios ya no contenga más elementos (`fragments.length > 0`).

Te dejo el snippet del código que menciono.

```js
const str = "   atención  la descripción de los síntomas, revisó detenidamente las     zonas afectadas y explicó detalladamente el problema y el uso de   los medicamentos que recetó  "

let fragments = str.replaceAll(/\s{2,}/g, " ").trim().split(/\s/);
let subarr = [];

while(fragments.length > 0)
  subarr.push(fragments.splice(0,10).join(' '))

console.log(subarr);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias esto es lo que necesitaba me funciona perfectamente

Comment: Excelente respuesta